# Check if file exist in folder?

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure how to do this. I need to execute an script.

The script needs to watch a folder for files created. If the files are created it will trigger a series of functions.

But prior to that, the script must ALWAYS check if a certain file exist. Because otherwise the script will not execute. The existing file needs to be moved before doing anything else.

I tried using the filechanged event but it will overwrite the existing file...

Is there a way to do this?

Here is the beginning of the script:

```
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true              # <-- set this according to your requirements
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

    Write-Host "The file '$name' at '$path'was $changeType at $timeStamp" -Fore white
    $lineas = (Get-Content $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.TXT | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
    Write-Host "El archivo contiene $lineas lineas" -Fore white

    if ($lineas -gt 3) {
        Write-Host "El archivo contiene información" -Fore white
        limpia
        leeyedita
        printpdf
        borrar
        renombra
    } else {
        Write-Host "El archivo NO contiene información" -Fore white
        borrar
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Test-Path` ?

Comment: My question is... how do I assure that the script is always looking if the file exist?

IF I used the filechanged event it will overwrite the file before I can do anything to it. 

So I need to have a constant way to check if the file exist prior to execute anything else...

Comment: I would start here. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/17/use-powershell-to-monitor-for-the-creation-of-new-files/

Comment: as much as I tried.. it didnt work. If I used the events, the old file will get overwritten.